# How do I make a VB.Net Form App wait for user input after every line?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm going to need to present a program in class and I want to have it so that the program waits for user input after every line so I can talk through it line-by-line. I effectively want Small Basic's TextWindow.Pause - is there an easy way of doing this?

For example, this is a snippet of my code (should swap the values of two selected elements, i and the element after i):

`For i = 0 To dataset.ToArray.Length - 1
            Dim tempInt As New Integer
            If dataset(i) > dataset(i + 1) Then
                tempInt = dataset(i)
                dataset(i) = dataset(i + 1)
                dataset(i + 1) = tempInt
            End If
        Next`

And this is what I'm looking for:

`For i = 0 To dataset.ToArray.Length - 1
WAIT
            Dim tempInt As New Integer
WAIT
            If dataset(i) > dataset(i + 1) Then
WAIT
                tempInt = dataset(i)
WAIT
                dataset(i) = dataset(i + 1)
WAIT
                dataset(i + 1) = tempInt
WAIT
            End If
WAIT
        Next`

(P.S. - if this code wouldn't give me my desired result i.e. swapping the values of the elements, how can I fix this? Hints please, not answeers - this *is* a school project after all!)

Comment: This is not a VBA question - please fix your tags

Comment: sleep in System.Threading

Comment: @Nathan_Sav --- No that would not allow user input.

Comment: Ah, sorry about the vba tag @TimWilliams! @Nathan_Sav, looks like that's time-based unfortunately...

Comment: Run the program with the Visual Studio debugger, step through the code line by line in your presentation.

Comment: I just saw the wait, and hinted based on that, a toggle Boolean on key press for the form would do, then a loop in between, then resetting Boolean, default state false, blnProgressCode, then Key press sets blnProgressCode to true, and code runs, setting to false before the next checking loop.

Comment: @LarsTech when you say debugger, what do you mean? Whenever I run my program, the drop-down near the Start button always says "Debug" - I suppose that means I'm already using it? If so, how can I step line-by-line?

Comment: On the line `For i = 0 To dataset.ToArray.Length - 1`, click in the gray margin to the left to set the break point.  You will get a red circle.  Run the program,  When the program hits that line, it will stop.  You can examine the variable's values by hovering your mouse over them.  Press F8 to move to the next line.  Repeat.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't give the desired result - I need to be able to watch my program as it works and the debugger closes the program. @BanForFun sorted it though, but thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Try This: (I know it's not the best answer :))

Add this function to your form:

```
Function delayread() As String
    Try
        Return My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\vbdelay.txt")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ""
    End Try
End Function
```

Then make another application and paste in this code:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown() Handles Me.KeyDown, Me.MouseDown
    Dim writer1 As New System.IO.StreamWriter(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\vbdelay.txt")
    writer1.Write("True")
    writer1.Close()
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
    Dim writer2 As New System.IO.StreamWriter(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\vbdelay.txt")
    writer2.Write("False")
    writer2.Close()
End Sub
```

Every time you want to wait for user input in your basic application put in: (Replace the "WAIT" with this)

```
Do Until delayread() = "True"
    Loop
```

Then run both applications.

---

*Note the input must be to the second application

Comment: The code I presented earlier was throwing up an error so I implemented your solution with a different portion of code:

http://pastebin.com/ehQCB4qp

I then pasted your other code into a new app. I ran both apps so that I had the blank design form of your app and the main menu of mine showing, but when I moved to the important form in my app the program closed! Have I used your code incorrectly?

Comment: Aha! After editing it a bit and making some changes to my code that I stupidly left out (I forgot to make the text in the textboxes update for one!) I managed to get it sorted. Thanks for your help - this solution was perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into *Aspect Oriented Programming*. The pauses you want is a cross-cutting concern and should not mix with your logic. Luckily, there are some tool meant for this job. As per [Wikipedia's AOP page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming),

> a programming paradigm that aims to increase modularity by allowing the separation of cross-cutting concerns.

There are quite a few frameworks around, [Castle Project](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) among them, which worked well for me. I used it when I wanted to add some log basically everywhere in a project without cluttering the functions with boilerplate calls.

(That being said, LarsTech suggests you run the program in a Visual Studio debugger, and I suggest you follow his advice if you are late.)

Comment: I'll have a look into it tomorrow and let you know if I managed to find anything useful. Thanks for your advice!